# How to show Multinode tree picker value on its Parent Node

Tags: node.js, umbraco7

Hi please need help how to render my multinode tree picker value (http://screencast.com/t/NTu1NqXsTmBz) to show it on its parent node named PORTFOLIO ..

i want the multinode picker value should be placed between the Portfolio and About section (http://screencast.com/t/F0Dnnv9a) but I don't know how yet i tried render it and still not work ..

here is the finish template : screencast.com/t/ar1zeZ43Pf6J

Node tree picker code:

```
@if (Model.Content.HasValue("mntp_pickContent"))
{
    var bannerListValue = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<string>("mntp_pickContent");
    <div id="container" class="container-portfolio">
     @foreach (var item in bannerListValue.Split(','))
        {
         var page = Umbraco.Content(item);
        <div class="col-md-4 element branding">
            <div class="portfolio-item flip ">
                <div class="flip-content">
                    <div class="front"> 
                        <a href="#"> <img width="360" height="249" src="@page.Url" class="attachment-project-thumb wp-post-image" alt="background4" /> </a> 
                    </div>
                            <div class="back">
                                <div class="back-content">
                                    <h4><a href="@page.contentLink" title="Project Name" class="open-popup">@page.contentTitle</a></h4>
                                    <div class="txt-project">
                                        <p>@page.contentsubTitle</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="@page.Url" class="open-popup more"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <!-- flip container -->
        </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

---

Parent Node Portfolio.cshtml

```
@{ if (Model.Content.HasValue("port_backImage"))
 {
     var bgport = Umbraco.TypedMedia(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<string>("port_backImage"));
    <section class="section-wrap section-portfolio" style="background-image: url(@bgport.Url)" id="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container-wrap row portfolio">
                <div class="container-wrap-title col-md-6">
                    <h2>@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("pageTitle")</h2>
                    <h6>@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("subTitleText")</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="container-wrap-subnav col-md-6">
                    <ul class="subnavigation" id="filters">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#" data-filter="*">show all</a></li>
                        @foreach (var portMenu in Model.Content.Children)
                        {
                            <li><a href="@portMenu.Url" data-filter=".@portMenu.UrlName">@portMenu.Name</a></li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on the Templating Engine you are using.

If you are using MVC, then you need to add your MNTP logic to a partial view.
See the following link: 
https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Templating/Mvc/partial-views

If you are using WebForms, then you will need to add your logic to a Razor file OR alternatively a UserControl (.ascx) file. See the following links:

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/templating/macros/

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/templating/macros/Razor/

http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials/introduction-to-umbraco/developer-introduction/using-net-user-controls